# Firebase Realtime Database Update Many Nodes at Once

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, chat

I have a chat app and want to create a count of unread messages.  Basically something like this if user1 were to be sending the message.

Is there some way to loop through all users to update vs having a function like below.  I am thinking there could be some way to map through all users and call update on each specifically instead, but can't seem to figure out the best approach

```
ref.child("Public").child("ChannelName").update({
  user1: 0,
  user2: old unread messages + 1,
  user3: old unread messages + 1,
  user4: old unread messages + 1
});
```

Currently using:

```
UNREAD_MESSAGES.once("value")
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(user => {
          let userKey = user.key;
          let userVal = user.val();
          // update unread messages count
          if (userKey !== currentUserID) {
            UNREAD_MESSAGES.update({
              [userKey]: userVal + 1
            });
          } else {
            UNREAD_MESSAGES.update({
              [userKey]: 0
            });
          }
        }
        )
      })
```

Comment: if a user is online, but the given channel is not the active channel (for example, multiple discord servers/channels), then when their client gets the push message (say, a new snapshot update), the user's app should be updating their 'unread message' count. Other parts of the system shouldn't even be AWARE of the Users, IMO

Comment: Where should the unread message count go then?  Here is my current database structure.  I have yet to add in the unread message count: https://gist.github.com/Sbphillips19/b9edc7f1174046ad4acad0fd005f7041

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update a value in Firebase Realtime Database, you will need to know its complete path. The Firebase Database does not support update queries, where you pass a condition and a calculation or value to the server.

If you'd be using Cloud Firestore (the other database that is part of Firebase), that *does* include a `FieldValue.increment()` operation that can be used in such a way.

To do your operation without the risk of a race condition on the Realtime Database, you will actually need to [run a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions); either on each counter, or across all counters.

Comment: I marked this as correct answer, but updated the code that I am using above.  Is that technically the best way to look through an update messages?  Am I better off moving this to cloud functions also?

Comment: "the best way" Nope. As said in the last paragraph of my answer, there's a race condition in there. The way to solve that is by [using a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).